# Como alterar a url de retorno ao direcionar para a página de login?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, autenticação, redirecionamento-de-url

Como eu posso alterar o valor de `ReturnUrl` passado à página de login quando o usuário estiver numa página específica e a sessão expirar?

Por exemplo, se o usuário estiver na página `www.meusite.com/seguranca.aspx` e a sessão finalizar, ao invés de direcionar por padrão para `www.meusite.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=seguranca.aspx` gostaria que fosse direcionada para outra página, como `www.meusite.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=default.aspx`.

Para as demais páginas, continuaria normal.

Comment: Essa aplicação é asp net, digo ela não é MVC?

Caso seja asp net, basta configurar nos métodos padrões do global.asax. Session_OnEnd:

void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E) {
    // Redirect para a sua pagina
}

Answer (score 1):

A única forma que vejo de fazeres isso é implementares o teu próprio módulo HTTP de autenticação.

Podes ver [aqui](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Security/FormsAuthenticationModule.cs) a implementação do `FormsAuthenticationModule` que controla a autenticação por Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que depende muito do que você pretende,
geralmente eu por exemplo, costumo verificar em atividades e páginas específicas SE e QUAL usuário está logado, caso ele não esteja logado se por exemplo ele estiver tentando chamar uma função específica, eu o redireciono para login, mas caso ele simplesmente está tentando acessar uma página ao qual não possui permissão, eu redireciono para a minha Default.aspx em questão.

acho que em geral se deve redirecionar ele para login, caso ele esteja tentando executar algo, ou acessar algo, mas caso ele não tenha permissão por exemplo, vai para a default.aspx.

desculpe se não cheguei ao ponto em que você quis chegar, mas foi onde consegui entender do seu problema.

Comment: A questão não é acesso a recursos não permitidos, mas simplesmente de que, ao terminar a sessão o usuário estando na página `seguranca.aspx`, ao invés de ser automaticamente redirecionado para o endereço `/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=seguranca.aspx` ele seja redirecionado para `login.aspx?ReturnUrl=default.aspx` ou outra qualquer que eu definir.

Comment: não sei se vai te ajudar, vou te oferecer um ponto de vista. Eu como usuário, se estou numa página por tempo suficiente que faça a minha sessão expirar, prefiro ser redirecionado para o login do que cair na página principal sem entender o motivo pelo qual fui parar lá, tem que lembrar que você sabe que a sessão dele caiu, mas o usuário muitas vezes nem sabe que isso existe e muito menos sabe quanto tempo pode ficar numa página sem fazer nada. Cair na página principal porque a sessão expirou, não vejo como uma boa prática, pode facilmente confundir o usuário, mas isso é só meu ponto de vista!